# Zooming to specific loaded layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-3

I'm trying to zoom to a layer that was loaded with a script, just like manually would be done by right clicking the layer and pressing the "Zoom to Layer" button.

I've tried several ways and the closest I got was using canvas but it wouldn't zoom in but instead it would open a secondary screen with the layer extended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **iface** (PyQGIS 3) there are 12 methods that involve "Zoom":

> zoomFull, zoomToActiveLayer, zoomToNext, zoomToPrevious, actionZoomActualSize, actionZoomFullExtent, actionZoomIn, actionZoomLast, actionZoomNext, actionZoomOut, actionZoomToLayer, actionZoomToSelected

and in **QgsMapCanvas** other 13 additional methods:

> zoomByFactor, zoomIn, zoomLastStatusChanged, zoomNextStatusChanged,
>   zoomOut, zoomScale, zoomToFeatureExtent, zoomToFeatureIds,
>   zoomToFullExtent, zoomToNextExtent, zoomToPreviousExtent,
>   zoomToSelected, zoomWithCenter

When I use, e.g. 'zoomToActiveLayer' iface method at Python Console, for **polygon1** as Active Layer (see following image):

```
zoomToActiveLayer
```

[image]

I got result of following image.

[image]

You can try out whatever of above methods (use 'help' for command syntax if it is necessary).

Answer (score 6):

This is what i do in a plugin to view a newly added layer.

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, layerName, 'ogr')
ex    = layer.extent()

# Add a small space/border on each side of the layer
hborder = ex.height() / 100
wborder = ex.width() / 100
ex.set(ex.xMinimum() - wborder, 
       ex.yMinimum() - hborder, 
       ex.xMaximum() + wborder, 
       ex.yMaximum() + hborder
)

# Find out if we need to transform coordinates
proj = QgsProject.instance()
if layer.crs().authid() != proj.crs().authid():
    print("Layer has not the same CRS as proj", 
          layer.crs().authid(), 
          proj.crs().authid()
    )
    tr = QgsCoordinateTransform(layer.crs(), proj.crs(), proj)
    ex = tr.transform(ex)

iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(ex)
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```